# How to change corresponding author (CA)? Always last author shows CA

Tags: formatting, titles, templates

I am preparing a manuscript using `nrc` LaTeX template. I downloaded the required files from following sites:

https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nrc?lang=en

I need to change the corresponding author. But, it always takes last author as corresponding author.

```
\author{X.Y}
\address{Address One}

\author{A.B}\correspond
\address{Address Two}

\author{P.Q}
\address{Address Three}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  Please, could you provide a complete MWE (Minimal Working Example) starting with `\documentclass` and ending in `\end{document}`.  We also try to avoid greeting formulae.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it. Just need to comment a line after last author (`%\correspond{author@email.address}`)

```
\author{X.Y}
\address{Address One}

\author{A.B}\correspond{author@email.address}
\address{Address Two}

\author{P.Q}
\address{Address Three}
%\correspond{author@email.address}
```

[image]